# How to make Apache mod_rewrite work properly on MacOs Ventura?

Tags: macos, apache, mod-rewrite, homebrew

Recently i moved to a new Mac and installed Apache / PHP following this tutorial :

https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-ventura-apache-multiple-php-versions

Everything is working as my prior machine EXCEPT the mod_rewrite module ; what i want is, not to have to put .php on my urls. So instead of

```
localhost/home/index.php
```

I just use

```
localhost/home/index
```

So here is my .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

This works on my remote server, but not on my local machine.

Also i enabled the mod_rewrite line on my httpd.conf file :

```
LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

What else should i look for ?

Comment: Presumably you also have `RewriteEngine On` in your .htaccess file? Otherwise that could explain it.

Comment: @MrWhite It was right. I don't know why but after a reboot, it worked

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explicitly turn on Rewrite Engine, so for example in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Note: Because this question is as of yet unanswered, I'm providing an answer based off of the comment from @MrWhite to the original question. It solved this same issue for me, but I don't know why this is the case. If anyone has any insight into what causes this please edit this answer accordingly.

Comment: "It solved this same issue for me, but I don't know why" - Do you mean by restarting Apache or rebooting your Mac (or including `RewriteEngine On`)? Changes to the server config (eg. enabling the rewrite module) would always require an Apache restart (but not necessarily a machine reboot). (It would seem the OP already had `RewriteEngine On` in place, since a "reboot" resolved the issue.)